# Parsing Time Data

Tags: r, time, cut

I'm trying to bin time data into 1 min intervals throughout the day. Based on the following [How to bin times from different days into time bins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193320/how-to-bin-times-from-different-days-into-time-bins), I've managed to generate the breaks using the following:

```
breaks <- format(seq.POSIXt(from = strptime("00:00:00", format = "%H:%M:%S"), to = strptime("23:59:59", format = "%H:%M:%S"), by="1 min"), format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

However, once I try to use cut, NAS get coerced instead

```
data$bins <- cut(data$TIME, breaks = breaks)
Warning message:
In sort.int(as.double(breaks)) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I've used the chron package to convert my data (hh:mm:ss format) into a time object and other operations seem to function properly.

Thanks!

Comment: Your statement about is generating the time breaks as character strings, this won't work in the cut function.  Without see an example of your data it is difficult to provide additional advice.

Comment: You are correct, just realized my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: `trunc(times("13:20:15"), "min")` will truncate a chron times object to minutes.  See ?trunc